# Save user authentication status in vuex state is safe Solution?

Tags: vue.js, authentication, vuex

I've watched various videos on spa vue authentication. All those videos provided a vuex based solution

Like this ;
They created function in getters such as **loggedIn** that it returns user authentication status .

**store.js**

```
[...]

state:{
    token: null,
    user: null
},
getters: {
    loggedIn: (state) => {
        return state.token && state.user ? true : false
    },
},

[...]
```

**Dashboard.vue** (This is a protected route)

```
[...]

beforeRouteEnter (to, from, next) {
    if(store.getters.loggedIn)
        next()
    else
        next({ name:'login' })

}

[...]
```

Everything is working correctly but I can change state manually by vue dev tools thus I can enter the protected route so authentication is not working properly.

**My questions :**

1. Can the user modify the vuex state in production mode?
2. Save user authentication status in vuex state is safe Solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can the user modify the vuex state in production mode?

Yes, the user can do *anything* to the state of the app. You can obfuscate some things, but you cannot prevent the user from inspecting or modifying the data of your app.

> Save user authentication status in vuex state is safe Solution?

It is one approach, and I do recommend it especially as your app size grows it will become easier to manage shared state in your app. But I wouldn't say it is "safe" or "unsafe".

> I can change state manually by vue dev tools thus I can enter the protected route so authentication is not working properly.

The app's behavior can be easily circumvented as you have described. You only have complete control over the server code. If the protected route becomes accessible on the client because the user tampered with the data using dev tools, then the server should reject any requests for privileged data that the protected route requires.

Comment: Therefore, no component can be completely hidden from the user perspective, only the data received from the server can be restricted.
For example, if I receive data from the server and display it in the dashboard component , An unauthorized user can see the dashboard component but cannot see any data because the data is received from the server.
This is true ?

Comment: Yes that is correct. You have no safety over the client code, only the server code.